# cascade layers with scss and vscode

Tags: css, sass

I would like to add layers to importing component's scss files in my main style.scss in vscode.

I have a style.scss file in which I @import my app's component's _compstyle.scss files with, and my vscode generates the final style.css with watch sass. My question is that is it possible to add cascade layers to the import, or use cascade layers with scss at all? I tried to set layers in my style.scss's first row like this:

```
@layer reset, default, comp
```

My initial import row looks like this:

```
@import "./comp/compname/compstyle";
```

I tried to add layers to it like this:

```
@import "./comp/compname/compstyle" layer(comp);
```

My vscode does not recognize the @layer rule here. Is it possible at all to use layers with sccs, or does it have something similar, or something to replace it with?

I could not find anything on this topic so far, so every bit of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: identical to question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/74791017/104380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to just compile the compstyle.css files from the compstyle.scss files and then create a style.css and use it like `@import "css/compstyle.css" layer(comp);`