# SCSS and @layers - how to make them work together?

Tags: sass

In my `styles.scss` file I have few imports with generic classes and functions:

```css
@import "css/generic.scss";
@import "css/functions.scss";
@import "css/layout.scss";
```

I'm trying to make those imports work in layers. I've tried the following:

```
@import "css/generic.scss" layer(utilities);
```

```
@layer utilitites {
  @import "css/generic.scss";
}
```

or wrapping all CSS code in the imports.

Every time I get the same error - that something from functions file is not available to be used later on. Usually it's a mixin defined in `functions.scss` that is being used in `layout.scss` but it's not available.

Is there a way to make it work? I'm guessing it's because of the SCSS components like mixins having some kind of scope?

Comment: [This answer](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/3240#issuecomment-1007004992) helped me to make layers work with SCSS, although the difference is that I am using `@use`  rule, so not sure it is the same with `@import` rules.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I couldn't get `@use` to work at all :/

Comment: Yeah, it took some time for me to figure `@use` rule and how to use it. I think for the starters you need to make sure you are using `dart-sass` as I don't think others libs support `@use` rule.

Comment: Ahh okay, that could be the problem. I'm using a PHP repo for Sass and perhaps it's not working there yet as it should

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to just compile the generic.css file from the generic.scss and then create a style.css and use it like `@import "css/generic.css" layer(utilities);`